# Error: Request Entity Too Large: head I get this error Intermittently

Tags: httprequest, http

I have tried reproducing this error and have no been able to on a regular basis 
I have allot of cookies but there small so don't think that's it. Also I notice that the refereed header from sales force was  5000 characters long. Which I assume counts against the size of the total request header. If anyone has experienced the same error please let me know the context and what you did to solve it.

Comment: I got that occasionally when trying to edit field sets. I simply refreshed and it worked the second. Not an answer just confirmation that someone else has seen this happen

Answer (score 1):

I came across this today when running a query in the developer console using execute anonymous to run some logic after querying my data.  The first time I saw the error when querying over 100 fields on Contact but for a single Id.   I cut the field list down and the query ran successfully.  However, after adding approx 100 Ids to my query the error came back, so I just had to run the script with approx. 10 records at a time.  Hope that helps.  Might also be related to querying many fields against a very large table, even if you WHERE clause is selective against Ids.